# Force-delete a branch in Git?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have created a branch `test` in my Git repository. Now I have no use for it. How can I force-delete this branch?

I tried the following command:

```
git branch -d test
```

But it returns an error.

Comment: `git branch -D test`. Capital `D`

Comment: please consider adding the error you were getting

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can force-delete a branch with the following command:

```
git branch -D test
```

By replacing `-d` with `-D`, you are telling git to delete the branch and that you don't care to merge changes from that branch.

Be careful, you can lose data.